# Big Query - different number of events and sessions in BigQuery and Analytics

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I query (normal SQL) the number of pageviews, hits, events and sessions per hostname using the following query:

```
SELECT 
  hits.page.hostname,
  SUM(IF(hits.type = 'PAGE',1,0)) AS pageviews,
  COUNT(hits.hitNumber) AS hits,
  SUM(IF(hits.type = 'EVENT',1,0)) AS events,   
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN hits.isInteraction IS TRUE THEN CONCAT(CAST(fullvisitorid as string),CAST(visitid as string)) END) AS sessions 
FROM `XXX_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181231' AND '20181231'
GROUP BY 1
```

If I compare the result with Google Analytics, pageviews and hits are the same, but there is a difference in events and sessions. Why? What have I done wrong?
Every help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
I managed to get the correct number of events with:

```
COUNT(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory) AS totalEvents
```

but still have problems with the sessions.

**Edit2:**
I found a solution for the sessions. Google Analytics does not consider whether a host changes within a session or not. Therefore, only the host of the first hit is considered.

```
(SELECT page.hostname FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits)))
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, how many events are you out? Differences between GA and BigQuery are to be expected and you should always look to BigQuery as your source of truth as it's dealing with raw data and not sampling, assuming your asking for the correct thing in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The difference is not big, but there is one. When I use: 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN totals.visits IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(CAST(fullvisitorid as string),CAST(visitid as string)) END)) AS sessions FROM... 

the numbers are equal. Would be great if someone can check if my query is correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: Reading the above it sounds like you have got the correct count of sessions now too?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is still a difference in the sessions.

Comment: I use a count distinct of `CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS visit_ref` to match sessions back to GA, if you are doing any kind of unnesting in your data then be careful of using `totals.` as you could end up counting duplicated values on unnested rows.

Comment: In my opinion, this does not work because an interaction needs to take place in the session. Therefore, the numbers can not be the same.